# rosserial: node_handle hardware.read()

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, node-handle, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
What does this line of code do (from [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/40f61b98e6865ec4127d8949158ee607d62a3aaf/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h#L246)):

```
int data = hardware_.read();
```

thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317567/rosserial:-node_handle-hardware.read()/) by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It reads (bytes) from whatever is currently templated as being the "hardware" that `rosserial` uses for communication with the (ROS) host. It's a [member variable](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/40f61b98e6865ec4127d8949158ee607d62a3aaf/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h#L107) of which the type depends on the [`Hardware` template argument](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/40f61b98e6865ec4127d8949158ee607d62a3aaf/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h#L99).

To make it more concrete: if the `NodeHandle` is specialised for an Arduino, it'll probably use the (first) serial port to read from / write to. If it were an embedded device that has an ethernet port, it'd probably be a TCP or UDP socket file handle. Etc, etc.

---

Edit:

> So is this statement correct? The "hardware" is the Arduino?

Well, to be precise: `hardware` actually points to whatever the underlying platform uses to transmit and receive bytes. For Arduinos, that's typically:

- hardware RS232
- software RS232 (some pins)
- Serial-over-USB

See [rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/611ed413de06f1218d09317594eecfc39655d7ed/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h) for the Arduino "serial type" class and [rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ros.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/611ed413de06f1218d09317594eecfc39655d7ed/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ros.h) for the Arduino specialisation of the `rosserial` template (note that it could use the serial and the `TcpHardware` types).

---

Edit 2:

> And for example the `uint32_t ms = hardware_.time();` function reads the clock from the Arduino and not from the host?

It's defined [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/611ed413de06f1218d09317594eecfc39655d7ed/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h#L108), as a member of `ArduinoHardware` and calls `millis()`, so it would seem so, yes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on 2019-03-05**:
Thanks for this nice answer.
So is this statement correct? The "hardware" is the Arduino?

**Comment by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on 2019-03-05**:
Thanks again.
And for example the `uint32_t ms = hardware_.time();` function reads the clock from the Arduino and not from the host?